# How to change each value in a JSON in python

Tags: python, json

```
output = {'name': 'StackOverflow',
  'competitors': [{'competitor': 'bing',
                   'link': 'bing.com'},
                  {'competitor': 'google',
                   'link': 'google.com'}],
  'acquisition': {'acquired_day': 16,
                  'acquired_month': 12,
                  'acquired_year': 2013,
                  'acquiring_company': {'name': 'Viggle',
                                        'permalink': 'viggle'}}}
```

I have code which looks like this:

```
def traverse(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.iteritems():
            print('dict_key', key)
            traverse(value)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for value in obj:
            traverse(value)
    else:
        print('value', obj)


traverse(output)
```

This code traverses the whole JSON and prints each value and key. I need to set each value to a random string

Comment: This is Python 2.x, right?

Comment: Is it JSON, parsed from text, or just nested Python objects?

Comment: when you call traverse, you just pass that random string that you want to set.

Comment: Please post example output you want to receive.

Comment: output = {'name': 'asdnasjndjsa,
  'competitors': [{'competitor': 'asdjsadnldas,
                   'link': 'asdjasndasd.com},
                  {'competitor': 'asdksadnklsda',
                   'link': 'sadklsadlkas.com'}],
  'acquisition': {'acquired_day': 1621321321,
                  'acquired_month': 122131232,
                  'acquired_year': 2013,
                  'acquiring_company': {'name': 'asdsadasjnasjohfoai',
                                        'permalink': 'asduasdhsau'}}}

Answer (score 1):

If you pass along a reference to the parent and a location with your values you can make the modifications in place:

```
def mangle(obj, parent = None, key = None):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.iteritems():
            mangle(value, obj, key)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for idx, value in enumerate(obj):
            mangle(value, obj, idx)
    else:
        parent[key] = 'nonsense'


mangle(output)

>>> pprint(output)
{'acquisition': {'acquired_day': 'nonsense',
                 'acquired_month': 'nonsense',
                 'acquired_year': 'nonsense',
                 'acquiring_company': {'name': 'nonsense',
                                       'permalink': 'nonsense'}},
 'competitors': [{'competitor': 'nonsense', 'link': 'nonsense'},
                 {'competitor': 'nonsense', 'link': 'nonsense'}],
 'name': 'nonsense'}
```

Comment: Note I changed your function name - we're not just tranversing.